# How to setup a custom command-line class in Joomla4?

Tags: joomla-4.x, cli

I'm interesting in developing a custom command-line class in Joomla4, but I don't know where to get started.

Can anyone provide a general example on how to set up a class for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

These are two references I think cover the basics and should get you started.

https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book/com-cli.html

https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/june-2022/joomla-4-a-powerful-cli-application

The second one is a little less focused on the development aspects, being a broader overview, but it does have a reference at the bottom with links to more reading.

Comment: Thanks, lemme try that first link before I accept the answer. :)